# Summing columns on based on various conditions using logic operators

Tags: r

I want to mutate columns with sumif-like, logic statements:

Sample Data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), X = c(10, 20, 15, 0, 15), Y = c(10, 0, 10, 15, 0), Z = c(0, 10, 10, 10, 0))

df
   ID  X   Y   Z   
1  A   10  10  0
2  B   20  0   10
3  C   15  10  10
4  D   0   15  10
5  E   15  0   0
```

I need to mutate columns:

- X + Y
- X + Z
- Y + Z
- X + Y + Z

But I need the sums in X + Y to be 0/blank if there are non-zeros in X, Y, and Z.

So for row 3, the X+Y+Z should equal 35, but the X+Y should equal 0/blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with Gregor's help:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  mutate(XY = ifelse(X != 0 & Y != 0 & Z == 0, X + Y, 0),
     XZ = ifelse(X != 0 & Y == 0 & Z != 0, X + Z, 0),
     YZ = ifelse(X == 0 & Y != 0 & Z != 0, Y + Z, 0),
     XYZ = ifelse(X != 0 & Y != 0 & Z != 0, X + Y + Z, 0))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
df %>% mutate(c1 = ifelse(X != 0 & Y != 0 & Z != 0, 0, X + Y),
              c2 = X + Z,
              c3 = Y + Z,
              c4 = X + Y + Z)
```